# Django Model ValueError

Tags: database, django, email, models

I'm accessing emails in my email server, taking the body of each email and then applying regular expressions to find the data necessary to populate my Django model.

This all works fine except for one field, which is linked as a foreign key to another model field. Despite the value in my email being the same as the one in listed in my other model, it fails....

The error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Humanities'": "Subject.faculty" must be a "Faculty" instance.
```

For example, say each school subject has to be part of a faculty. When populating the database via a form, for the Subject's faculty field I drop down the menu to a list of faculty values/instances as there is a foreign key relationship defined in my model i.e. for the faculty field I can choose from Humanities, Art, Design Technology etc.

But when I find the value 'Humanities' in my email and try to add it to the database model, I get the error above.

Anyone shed any light on this? Am I being stupid or is it more than a ValueError as to me, the values are the same in both cases

Thank you

More code as requested:

```
class Faculty(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
  leader = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  email = models.EmailField()
  mailing_list = models.ManyToManyField("Contact", null=True)

class Subject(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)   
  faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty, to_field="name")
  faculty_head = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Let's see your models and some code!

Comment: Please try to reproduce the problem in a shell (./manage.py shell - don't forget to install ipython to get a better shell), and then post the shell session in the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to assign a string "Humantities" to a `ForeignKey` relationship. This doesn't make sense. You need to either find or create the actual `Faculty` object with the name "Humanities" and assign it to the `Subject`. Something like this in your view (depending on how your form is set up):

```
if form.is_valid():
  faculty_str = form.cleaned_data['faculty']
  (faculty, was_created) = Faculty.objects.get_or_create(name=faculty_str, ...)
  # It's hard to tell if you are using a ModelForm or just a normal Form. Anyway, assume we already have access to the Subject object
  subject.faculty = faculty
  subject.save()
```

[`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: So rather than simply supplying the value, I have to find and then directly refer to the Faculty object that already exists in my database?

Comment: Exactly. You assign the instance of `Faculty` (either created or retrieved from the DB) to your `subject.faculty` field and then save the changes back to the DB with `subject.save()`.

Comment: I think this is probably the right direction but just to clarify I can populate the model fine via forms, it is the values I get after ive applied regex to an email then try and populate the model that is giving me trouble

Comment: Django is making your life easy with the forms. It is managing the ForeignKey relationship behind the scenes while showing you a human friendly string ("Humanities") in the dropdown to describe what object the FK is related to. When you are manually searching the email and doing it youself, you don't have that luxury - you have to manually find or create the object representing "Humanities" and create the relationship between the two

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head! Makes sense now you've explained it. All works well now. Thank you Sir

Comment: PS I've clicked the green tick to signal this was the correct answer is there anything else I need to do to so you get reps etc?

Comment: haha, no. If an answer successfully addresses your problem then accept it with the green tick. If there are no answers but you figure out the problem yourself you can write your own answer to the problem and except that. You can also upvote and downvoate answers if you think they are good/bad by hitting the arrows above the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Your value is 'Humanities' perhaps you mean to search for Humanities (without quotes).

Comment: Yeah I did think that but I couldn't understand how the '' got there in the first place as in the email it is not in quotes

Comment: When I print the values before I submit and save them to the models there are not quotations which is why I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Faculty instance first.

```
faculty = Faculty(name='', leader='', email='')
faculty.save()

subject.faculty = faculty
subject.save()
```

Comment: Added my models. The Humanitites faculty already exists in my model which is why I was surprised I got the error I did - as the Faculty instance with the same value already exists